# Potential causes of Atmel "system" failure after reflash with same binary

Tags: flash, atmel

I'm working on a small "cartridge"-like subsystem which attaches to the main device via a 20-pin connector.

On the cartridge, there is an ATmega16a microcontroller and an AT45DB081D flash. I needed to modify a couple of bytes in the flash (external to MCU), so I did the following:

- Used a SOIC-8 test clip to connect the flash chip to an SPI interface on a Raspberry Pi.
- Used flashrom to read the binary contents 3 separate times.
- Used sha512sum to ensure the binaries were identical - they were.
- Modified the binary and flashed it back to the device - it verified.

I then noticed that the host device identified the cartridge as invalid/faulty, so I reflashed the original binary.

The device still recognises the "cartridge" as faulty even after reflashing the original binary, so my  question is:

Are there any mechanisms in this flash device which would allow the MCU to identify it as errant, even after reflashing the original binary as seen by flashrom?

Comment: Did you erase before re-programming?

Comment: No I didn't. It was my understanding that flashrom reads the existing contents of the flash, compares that with your binary, then only overwrites addresses that are different. It then verifies the write, so I can't see how the contents of the flash could be any different to what I expect.

Comment: Was the original binary data correctly read out? A badly connected jumper wire could end up reading all bits as 0 or 1. Reading it three times would still always match identical garbage.

Comment: The data contained strings that would suggest it was valid.

Comment: Verify the contents of the external flash, any of its lockable configuration bits, the MCU flash contents, and **also the MCU fuses**.  Beware that if you hold an ATmega in reset while manipulating the SPI lines with something else you may accidentally perform an ISP operation corrupting the contents or fuses.  Use a hot air tool to replace both the flash and the ATmega one at a time and see which the problem "follows".  Debug the issue from the software of the host system, or use a logic analyzer to monitor communication and compare working and non-working cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you damaged something on your "cartridge" when you attached the test clip. It sounds like you were connecting a powered Raspberry Pi in parallel with the ATmega16 and possibly other devices on your cartridge. This kind of thing must be done carefully to isolate the flash from the rest of the circuit during programming.

Comment: That's very possible. All active devices on-board accepted 3.3V VCC, but there might have been some nasty reverse powering occurring somehow. I'll check it out.